# Clicking a URL inside the Firefox error console no longer opens the source! FF 4

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox

Working on a web application and find the Firefox error console to be indispensable.

However I recently upgraded to FF 4 and now when I click errors in the console, the source code doesn't come up like it used to. Not sure it's related to the upgrade but timing is about right.

I've looked over about:config options, made sure the console is enabled, etc. Spent a long time with google trying to find someone else with this problem... nothing.

I get the "hand" cursor when hovering over the URL as if clicking it will do what I expect. However, nothing at all happens. Nada.

I've looked around for hidden windows and even tiny ones but can't find anything...

Any ideas?

Comment: All FF extions require an upgrade for v4, it might take a while till FireBug is stable again for FF4. You might want to report the bug to the FireBug team instead.

Comment: Hmm, good idea but I'm actually referring to the native error console. Just to see, I disabled all extensions but it did not help.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem might be but I'm on FF4 in Win 7 and the native JS console seems to work just fine for me (must note that I do have Firebug installed as well) so a change in FF itself can be ruled out - there must be something different about your particular install/OS.

Comment: Thanks, I figured the same but that confirms it. Anyone have any ideas as to what might be misconfigured?? It's gotta be something simple!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't exactly figure out why this is happening, but I did find that it only happens when I have the Error Console window on a different display as the main window. I use 2 displays to make debugging easier and moving the error console window to the main display makes it work again.

On a Mac, FWIW.